# jquery separate the onclick events of wrapped elements

Tags: jquery, events, element

I have an anchor link inside a div.  I would like both the anchor link and div to process onclick events separately, but right now clicking on the anchor link also triggers the onclick event for the div.  How do I prevent this?

Here's the code:

```
<html>
     <head>
     <style>
     #box {
          background-color: #ccffcc;
          width: 400px;
          height: 200px;
     }
     </style>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#mailto").click(function(event) {
                    // correctly opens an email client if clicked
                    $("a[@href^='http']").attr('target','_blank');
                    return( false );
               });

               $("#box").click(function() {
                    // always goes to the home page, even if the #mailto id is clicked
                    window.location = '/index.php';
               });
          });
     </script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="box">
          <a  href="mailto:someone@psomewhere.com" id="mailto">someone@psomewhere.com
    </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way for me to stop execution of the code after the mailto is loaded?

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to make sure your html is valid, so finish the a tag off:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@psomewhere.com" id="mailto">someone@psomewhere.com<a/>
```

and if that still causes problems try this.

```
$("#mailto").click(function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
    if(event.srcElement == 'HTMLAnchorElement')
    { 
        //Process
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The event is bubbling up the DOM tree, `e.stopPropagation();` will stop that.

```
$("#mailto").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // correctly opens an email client if clicked
    $("a[@href^='http']").attr('target', '_blank');
    return (false);
});

$("#box").click(function() {
    // always goes to the home page, even if the #mailto id is clicked
    window.location = '/index.php';
});​
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/uwJXK/
**About stopPropagation()** http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to your anchor not being closed properly. Or it certainly won't be helping